# Laravel: Strange bug with cache:clear and request()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm experiencing a weird bug with artisan cache:clear.
Here's my function:

```
public static function getSegments()
{
    $json = file_get_contents(base_path().'/routes/segments/post.json', true);
    $segments = json_decode($json);
    $locale = request()->segment(1);

    return $segments->$locale;
}
```

Now if I run: `php artisan cache:clear`

I get this error:

> ErrorException Undefined property: stdClass::$
>
> ➜  93▕         return $segments->$locale;

The $json value is a perfectly valid object and the value returned by request()->segment(1) is correct.
Even weirder, the app works fine in the browser, there is no error or whatever.

Now if I set the $locale variable like this:

```
$locale = 'fr';
```

Everything works.

So I try with strval just in case:

```
$locale = strval(request()->segment(1));
```

But the error is back again.
Can someone tell me where is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cache:clear` is an Artisan command, so there won't be a request segment to get, and `$locale` won't have an actual value. You can check to see if the command line is hitting that function and defaulting the value if it is:

```
$locale = \App::runningInConsole() ? 'fr' : request()->segment(1);
```